# While developing multihomed reliable udp, how can I detect that a link is down using mininet?

Tags: python, networking, udp, mininet, multihomed

Here is the topology:

```
      -----s0---s1-----
 h1 --|               |--h2
      -----s2---s3-----
```

h1 pumps a file to h2 using UDP in a reliable way. The link between s0 and s1 may be down. Then it should continue to send the data using only the bottom path. Is there a way to detect that the link is down?

So far I created two python sockets in h1 and two in h2 for each path. Using select.select I can get the ready socket to read ack's. If timeout occurs I can retransmit. However, when the link is down, I cannot know that it is down.

Answer (score 3):

If you *had* to do this from scratch for your implementation for whatever reason;

> Try to ping the otherwise, wait for an ack; timeout if you don't
>   receive an ack within a time period; try the other path. Any reason
>   you aren't using TCP? Implementing reliability atop UDP is basically
>   what TCP is over IP.

See [The 3-way handshake](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionEstablishmentProcessTheThreeWayHandsh-3.htm) for an illustration and guide on how TCP handshakes are established.

---

You could also consider using [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) which is multihomed, stream based transmission control protocol. Quite a few platforms support it including Linux, BSD, Windows and others.

There is also a [Python SCTP lirbary](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysctp)

It's as simple as:

```
import socket
import sctp

sk = sctpsocket_tcp(socket.AF_INET)
sk.connect("10.0.1.1")
```

And implements most of the same interfaces as [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

Comment: Then you have some *learning* to do. You have to develop a way to determine if the other link is still alive. If you have already implemented *reliable* file transmission this shouldn't be *that* hard. Also SCTP != TCP.

Comment: You may do what is done in clustering, which is have one connection for the actual data transfer, and another for a "stay alive" status check. Good luck @James.

Comment: @boardrider Haha thanks but this is my advice; not my problem to solve :) Although I admit it would be interesting to implement :)

Comment: Sorry, @James, mea culpa: I was supposed to put `@ uLtRaLoVeR` at the end of my comment.

Comment: No problems :) No harm!